# Problems with JSP outside Eclipse

Tags: java, jsp

People, my problem is:

I have a JSP page, which calls a Servlet, and then the Servlet calls it again... Well, the point is that inside the Eclipse browser everything works fine, but when I deploy to Tomcat (deploy: CTRL-C on Eclipse project folder, and CTRL-V in webapps) and run on Chrome, it keeps giving me this error:

```
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Even though the jars are inside `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.
Any ideas?

Comment: Export your web application as war file and then paste that war file in eclipse webapps folder and start the server or deploy the war via tomcat manager.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem with jar file , [download this jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/jstl/jars/jstl-1.1.0.jar)  and redeploy might help.